# Vuetify make items stay in a single row and resize based on content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I'd like to have a single v-row with a button on the right edge and fill the rest of the space with many buttons inside v-chip-group. There are more buttons then the space available. The v-chip-group should shrink/fill the space between the left edge and the right button (the v-chip-group component provides arrows so you can "page" through the content).

Currently the right button is pushed to a new row instead and the v-chip-group fills the whole row.

```
<v-row no-gutters>
   <v-col>
      <v-chip-group>
         <v-btn text @click="goTo(drive)" v-for="drive in drives" :key="drive.name">{{ drive.name }}</v-btn>
         <v-btn text @click="goTo(home)">Home</v-btn>
         <v-btn text v-for="location in favourites" :key="location.name">{{ location.name }}</v-btn>
      </v-chip-group>
   </v-col>
   <v-col>
      <v-btn text><v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon></v-btn>
   </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Comment: Can you put columns in a row? One bigger one (e.x. 10) and the second smaller for a btn (2)? Will that be ok?

Comment: no, it works for one size but gets messed up when you scale the width down. also I need as much space as possible, I only need the "last" column to fill the space the button needs

Comment: OK, did you try with a flex-box, `v-flex` components?

Comment: I did not, I don't know how to use it really. Can you point me to some docs? I find the vuetify docs about grids and flex quite lacking, can't make a sence of it. All the tutorials on 3rd party sites are about vuetify v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your goal 100% but seems like you want to add the `cols` property to your columns. This way the right most button will never slide into a new row and the chip-group will use the most available space.
This behaviour defaults to all screen sizes. If you wanted the breakpoint `lg` to behave differently, you can add `lg="6"` for example.

```
    <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="11">   <--- here
          <v-chip-group>
            <v-btn text v-for="drive in drives" :key="drive.name">
              {{ drive.name }}
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn text>Home</v-btn>
            <v-btn text v-for="location in favourites" :key="location.name">
              {{ location.name }}
            </v-btn>
          </v-chip-group>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="1">   <---- and here
          <v-btn text><v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon></v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
```

Comment: hi, it kinda works if there's one button, however on small screen it puts the button too much to the right for some reason, so that a small horizontal scrollbar appears

Comment: Can you setup a simple codesandbox with your data? I tried recreating your setup and only used dummy data. Maybe I did something a little bit different than you

Comment: I can't make vuetify work in codesandbox :/ it's probably not the data but the rest of the code. this is the whole code which is displayed inside a v-dialog: https://codeshare.io/G8lQ8B . I had to use d-flex because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029810/vuetify-make-content-table-of-card-fit-inside-it also if I put rows directly in the container every time I click anything in the table it moves half a screen down for some reason

Comment: I have put the button on another row for now so I can continue working on it and this is how it looks like in chrome and safari for some reason https://ibb.co/XtThTXb https://ibb.co/85y9zBy

Comment: I'll try and setup a codesandbox later so you can check if everything I put in there is correct. Then we can get to the debugging from there

Comment: Here is the code in isolation: Is this the way you wanted it to work out? https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-6xge5?file=/src/layout.vue

Comment: yeah this is fine by itself

Comment: So there has to be another issue with your setup if the code is working standalone. You can now try and add more and more pieces of your code and see when it breaks. Then you know where the "actual" issue comes from. Feel free to add the code directly into the sandbox. once you hit Ctrl + S, it automatically creates a new url for you

Comment: thanks for taking the time :) so even with your example if you make the window really narrow, the X button gets pushed to the side a bit, on iphone se it's actually half way out of the screen and makes the thing scroll horizontally. it's weird because the left side keeps the margin. also I've added a table beneath https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-vhpxp and the row is ignored in safari as seen in this picture (same on ios and macos) https://ibb.co/KbtF0V6 (works fine in chrome on windows and android)

Comment: The smallest I can get any browser to go is 304px in width and I can't see any issues. That's smaller than any phone I know of. I cannot debug iPhones since I don't have one at hand currently, sorry. The codesandbox you sent works the same on my phone (galaxy s10+) as it does on desktop. Can't see any difference at all. Really weird! Can you take a screenshot of how it looks on your end using the iPhone?

Comment: I've posted an image in the last post (the ibb.co link) also 3 posts above that there are more screenshots of the same thing the table is halfway through the row for some reason :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214831/discussion-between-rie-and-jacklin-heirdom).